# Using msbuild.exe to build a project with a dependency requiring a different Platform property

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have two fairly straightforward C# projects: An executable that can build as either x86 or AnyCPU, which references (via `<ProjectReference>`) a DLL project that only has an AnyCPU configuration. This all works as expected within Visual Studio.

I am trying to build the x86 version of the executable project (and its dependencies) from the command line, with `/p:Platform="x86"`. This causes the build of the DLL project to fail. (Whereas `/p:Platform="AnyCPU"` works, presumably because it is valid for both projects.)

The full command line I am using is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild MyProject\MyProject.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86"
```

What are my options for getting this build to work from the command line? Preferably without modifying the DLL project at all, or modifying the projects in ways that interfere with using them normally in Visual Studio.

(The ultimate goal here is a batch file that can build a clean version of the project for distribution.)

---

Additional info:

Both projects have "Debug" and "Release" configurations. The executable project has "x86" and "AnyCPU" available under Platform. The DLL project has only "AnyCPU" available under Platform. The "Platform target" option matches the "Platform" in all cases. (There is no "Prefer 32-bit" option, as I am on VS2010.)

The error seems to be a compilation-related error ("no unsafe code allowed") in the DLL, which -- although I am not 100% sure -- seems to be because none of the `<PropertyGroup>` elements in the DLL project are being matched (due to `Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "` etc) that would specify necessary parameters for compilation (eg `AllowUnsafeBlocks` and `DefineConstants`).

Comment: The Platform property set the *solution platform*.  A configuration detail that only matters to C++ projects. But the actual setting you want to change is the one that appears on the Project > Properties > Build tab.  As long as you add multiple platforms, it is rather important that they match or confusion will be fatal.  They normally don't, project defaults are AnyCPU for the platform but the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox checked.  Be sure to change the setting both for the Debug and the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand what you are saying. The "Platform target" in the project settings (ie: `<PlatformTarget>` in the project file) matches the "Platform" specified by `$(Platform)` (ie: whatever platform is selected for the build) in the normal way you would expect for project files, eg: `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">`. Visual Studio will build the x86 EXE + AnyCPU DLL combination just fine. How can I do this from the command line? Being able to build the EXE in both configurations is intended.

Comment: Hmya, that's what I mean with "fatal".  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  There are two comboboxes at the top and the two settings you care about, "Platform target" and "Prefer 32-bit".  There are 4 possible values for the comboboxes, the combination of Debug/Release and x86/AnyCPU.  Write down all the values of the settings for these 4 combinations and post them in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant Appended that information to the end of my question. It seems to me that my question may be along the lines of "is there a way to intercept whatever `<ProjectReference>` does" (it would be simple enough to build the DLL separately). I'm not sure how practical that actually is, though. But VS obviously makes this work (the x86 _solution_ "platform" uses the AnyCPU DLL _project_ "platform").

Comment: VS2010, ouch, hard to repro.  So this is actually about the "Allow unsafe code" checkbox in the DLL project.  Same recipe, you have 4 possible values and the platform target setting for the DLL project plays no role because you want AnyCPU for all 4.  Make sure the checkbox is ticked for all 4 possible combinations.

Comment: @HansPassant What you're suggesting seems to be "just go in and add the `$(Configuration)|$(Platform)` combinations you're passing in, and give it the right settings". Which seems more like a work-around (also kind of painful, as I am trying to avoid modifying the DLL's project file). I guess this is more of a "how does `<ProjectReference>` work" question than a "make the errors go away" question.

Comment: My question is possibly similar to this question, which itself didn't really get a satisfying answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348645/building-visual-studio-project-with-different-platforms-via-msbuild?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... First of all, MSBuild can build solution files. This does exactly what you'd expect:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86"
```

The result is an x86 executable with an AnyCPU DLL (as the solution specifies).

There are a few people out on the internet suggesting that its behaviour is not a *perfect* match for Visual Studio in some obscure cases. But it seems to work just fine for my purposes. (I think they were having issues with the order things get built in.)

I knew that MSBuild could build a solution file, but -- oops -- I neglected to test it on my simple reproduction case, after it failed on the more complex thing I'm working on.

---

The above, alone, isn't enough for a fully satisfying answer, particularly if there is a need to customise things. The way MSBuild builds solution files is to create a dummy project file, based on the solution file. This can be inspected by first setting an environment variable like so:

```
set MSBuildEmitSolution=true
```

This will emit the dummy project file next to the solution file, which can then be inspected.

I haven't completely analysed what it is doing, but it looks fairly straightforwardly like it is using the [`<MSBuild>` task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) with the `Projects` parameter that is itself passing in the solution-specified `Configuration` and `Platform` appropriate for each project. According to the documentation it seems to be using the ones specified in `AdditionalProperties`. ([This](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,884435b3-037f-4f7a-972f-d6dc9b6326b6.aspx) also seems useful to know.)

---

For reference, here is some relevant code extracted from the generated project file:

```
<Target Name="Build" Outputs="@(CollectedBuildOutput)">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" BuildInParallel="True" Properties="BuildingSolutionFile=true; CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents=$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents); SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir); SolutionExt=$(SolutionExt); SolutionFileName=$(SolutionFileName); SolutionName=$(SolutionName); SolutionPath=$(SolutionPath)" SkipNonexistentProjects="%(ProjectReference.SkipNonexistentProjects)">
    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CollectedBuildOutput" />
  </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Where `@(ProjectReference)` is grabbing data from:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="X:\Solution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
    <ToolsVersion>
    </ToolsVersion>
    <SkipNonexistentProjects>False</SkipNonexistentProjects>
    <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=Release; Platform=x86; VisualStudioVersion=10.0</AdditionalProperties>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Include="X:\Solution\DLLProject\DLLProject.csproj">
    <ToolsVersion>
    </ToolsVersion>
    <SkipNonexistentProjects>False</SkipNonexistentProjects>
    <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=Release; Platform=AnyCPU; VisualStudioVersion=10.0</AdditionalProperties>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

(Note the different `AdditionalProperties`.)